# iPhone - Launching selectors from a different class

Tags: iphone, class, uitableview, selector, nsnotificationcenter

I'd like to reload a table view which is in another class called "WriteIt_MobileAppDelegate" from one of my other classes which is called "Properties". I've tried to do this via the NSNotificationCenter class - the log gets called but the table is never updated.

Properties.h:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NameChanged"
              object:[WriteIt_MobileAppDelegate class]
               userInfo:nil];
```

WriteIt_MobileAppDelegate.m

> -(void)awakeFromNib {
>
> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
>               selector:@selector(reloadItProperties:)
>                name:@"NameChanged" object:self];
>
> }

```
- (void) reloadItProperties: (NSNotification *)notification {

 NSLog(@"Reloading Data"); //this gets called
[[self navigationController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 [self.tblSimpleTable reloadData];
 [self.tblSimpleTable reloadSectionIndexTitles];
 // but the rest doesn't
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the underlying data is updated before it reaches reloadItProperties?  Add logging of the updated data in that NSLog line.  Also, in the postNotificationName, you probably want `self` instead of `[WriteIt_MobileAppDelegate class]`.

Comment: yes, the data is changed. adding "self" did nothing, it just prevented the NSLog from coming up. Can I call the selector somehow differently?

Comment: Although it isn't the problem, in postNotificationName, you probably want self.  However, as ChriB mentions, in `addObserver`, you should change object parameter from self to nil.  With self there, you will only listen to notifications from self (which is WriteIt).  Though it doesn't explain why reloadItProperties was getting called anyway.  Is there any other code that calls reloadItProperties other than the postNotificationName for NameChanged?

Comment: it now works.DyingCactus, changing it to nil changed it all. thanks so much!

Comment: post your comment as an answer and i will give you the green tick :)

Comment: Thanks but ChriB was first to point out the problem with addObserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using the `object` parameter wrong:

[addObserver:selector:name:object:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:)

> **notificationSender**
>   The object whose
>   notifications the observer wants to
>   receive;
>   that is, only notifications
>   sent by this sender are delivered to
>   the observer. If you pass nil, the
>   notification center doesn’t use a
>   notification’s sender to decide
>   whether to deliver it to the observer.

Comment: i don't think so, [WriteIt_MobileAppDelegate class] is the only object that even toggles the NSLog. Is there another way of toggling the selector so that it updates the tableview?